# How to sum the values assigned to a key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries like below:

```
A=[
    {key1 : val11, key2 : val21, key3 : val31, key5 : val51, key6 : val61},
    {key2 : val22, key3 : val32, key5 : val52, key6 : val62},
    {key1 : val13, key2 : val23, key4 : val43, key5 : val53},
    {key1 : val14, key3 : val34, key4 : val44, key5 : val54, key6 : val64},
    {key4 : val45, key5 : val55, key6 : val65}
]
```

As you see the length of the dictionaries are not the same and also the `key : value` in each dictionary are not necessarily similar. I was wondering how to sum the values assigned for each key in all dictionaries:

For instance for `key4: (val43 + val44 + val45)` or for `key3: (val31 + val32 + val34)`.

Comment: `sum(d.get(mykey, 0) for d in mylist)`?

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Well, it would have been more useful if you gave it a try and presented how far you got "on your own".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with this -

```
A = [{1 : 5, 2  : 3, 3 : 4}, {1 : 1, 5: 10, 3: 2}, {100 : 2}]
```

Here's one way of getting what you want, using the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure -

1. Convert each dict to a `Counter` using `map`
2. Sum each `Counter` object with `sum`

```
from collections import Counter
r = sum(map(Counter, A), Counter())
```

```
r
Counter({1: 6, 2: 3, 3: 6, 5: 10, 100: 2})
```

The great thing about `Counter`s is that you can add them up, quite nicely.  The second argument to `sum` is the start of the "sum". If you want a dictionary back (instead of a `Counter`), call `dict(r)`.

Note that this solution works when your dicts only have keys with numeric values.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. In following, I would be so thankful if you could kindly explain how to calculate the standard error of mean (sem) here. 
Cheers, 
Alex

Comment: @user9185533 That's not how this site works. If you have a different question, you're supposed to open a new question. Can you please do that? Also, accept an answer if _this_ question was solved.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenient. I am going to post my question as a new one!

Answer (score 2):

You may also use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to get the count of all the values corresponding to each key. All you need to do is to iterate each element and sum the values to the `defaultdict`. For example:

```
my_list = [
     {'key1': 2, 'key2': 7},
     {'key2': 6, 'key3': 8},
     {'key1': 7, 'key4':9} 
 ]

from collections import defaultdict
my_counter = defaultdict(int)

for my_dict in my_list:                 # iterate your `list`
    for key, value in my_dict.items():  # iterate "key", "value" pairs of your `dict`
        my_counter[key] += value        # sum the "value" and add to the dict
```

This will return you the `dict` as:

```
>>> my_counter
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'key3': 8, 'key2': 13, 'key1': 9, 'key4': 9})
```

Comment: Many thanks for your responses.

In following, I would be so thankful if you could kindly explain how to calculate the standard error of mean (sem) here.

Cheers,
Alex