# Standard error of mean (sem) in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In list of dictionaries like below:

```
A=[
{key1 : val11, key2 : val21, key3 : val31, key5 : val51, key6 : val61},
{key2 : val22, key3 : val32, key5 : val52, key6 : val62},
{key1 : val13, key2 : val23, key4 : val43, key5 : val53},
{key1 : val14, key3 : val34, key4 : val44, key5 : val54, key6 : val64},
{key4 : val45, key5 : val55, key6 : val65}
]
```

I have been already able to sum the values assigned for each key in all dictionaries. However I have difficulty in calculating the Standard error of mean (SEM) for each key. So, I would be so appreciated if you could guide me to calculate the SEM corresponding to each key.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Pretend it's been years since I took a statistics class and I don't remember what the standard error of mean is.

Comment: Probably there is a module or package available which could do it.

Comment: Again not even an attempt to create code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142074/how-to-sum-the-values-assigned-to-a-key-in-a-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the Standard Error of mean for a certain key, you first need to find the standard deviation for that key:

Formula for SEM: `e = o/sqrt(n)`, where `s` is the SEM, `o` is the standard deviation, and `n` is the sample size ([1](http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/A103735.html)):

```
import statistics #for simple calculation of the standard deviation of a list
A=[
 {'key1' : 1, 'key2' : 21, 'key3':31, 'key5':51, 'key6':61},
 {'key2': 22, 'key3' : 32, 'key5':52, 'key6':62},
 {'key1':13, 'key2':23, 'key4':43, 'key5':53},
 {'key1':14, 'key3':34, 'key4':44, 'key5':54, 'key6':64},
 {'key4':45, 'key5':55, 'key6':65}]
full_keys = set([i for b in [c.keys() for c in A] for i in b])
data_listings = {i:list(filter(lambda x:x is not None, map(lambda y:y.get(i), A))) for i in full_keys}
error_listing = {a:statistics.stdev(b)/float(len(b)) for a, b in data_listings.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'key5': 0.31622776601683794, 'key1': 2.4113927126900783, 'key3': 0.5091750772173155, 'key4': 0.3333333333333333, 'key6': 0.45643546458763845, 'key2': 0.3333333333333333}
```